# DSC runs but it doesn't appear to have completed the configuration

Tags: powershell, dsc

I have created a DSC configuration file, a very basic setup to create a folder and a text file with the word HELLO. The configuration is only run on my machine. The steps followed was to start the configuration and I have a MOF, then in the configuration folder I ran the MOF.

Powershell shows the configuration is running but no folder or text file is created. There are no error messages shown. Nothing. When I run Get Configuration shows that it is absent.

What reasons are there why the configuration is not completing and how can I fix this?